# My app on iPad can't read photo after iOS9.3

Tags: ios, iphone, image, ipad

My app only support iPhone device, it can run correctly under iOS9.2 on both iphone and iPad. But after updating to iOS9.3 and iOS9.3.1, my app on iPad can't read user's image. (Both ALAsset and PhAsset have the same problem. )

The image will return nil, and I ensure it's a bug, because it can read image correctly, when I change my support device to universal in Xcode.
  Is it a bug for iOS? Or it becomes the rule? All app need to support universal ??

What's the fastest way to make myapp support iPad? I just want to use the scaling like the way iPhone app run on iPad.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem from last 7 days and couldn't find anything on google until now. Please update the status of your issue if you find any workaround.

Comment: I can't find any quick solution, and I decide to make my app into support universal. This means support both iPad and iPhone. The main efforts are the resolution issues. iPhone is 16:9(320x568 for logical resolution) and iPad is 4:3(768x1024 for logical resolution). To speed up the modification and no change for my art images, so I put my content int the middle on 4:3 screen. In this way, I spent about 3 full work-days to develop and  and debug for supporting iPad. Now it's wait for review.  One good thing to support iPad, users can easily search on app store when he use iPad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find any quick solution, and I decide to make my app into support universal. 
This means support both iPad and iPhone. 
The main efforts are the resolution issues. iPhone is 16:9(320x568 for logical resolution) and iPad is 4:3(768x1024 for logical resolution).

To speed up the modification and no change for my art images, so I put my content int the middle on 4:3 screen.

One good thing to support iPad, users can easily search on app store when he use iPad.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced same kind of problem two days ago, I think you need to update your xcode. Update your xcode to the latest version 7.3
It worked in my case.

Comment: But, I already updated xcode to 7.3. It happen in the app built by xcode 7.3. do I need any change?  The app launched on app store is not built by xcoe 7.3. But I tested in 7.3 with debug mode, it has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I met exactly the same problem and I fixed it.
[image]

Comment: It doesn't work for me. In my test for iPad mini, .scale is 2, it's file to use it. BTW, Both phasset and ALAsset fail. It seems fail because of the right to access photos, but I don't know how to make it work.    [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageForAsset:asset targetSize:size contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill options:options resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {
                cell.imageView.image = result;  -->result is always nil 
            }];
result is always nil.

Comment: I think the size of the image that you request is too big, and it is a bug for iOS9.3. May be you could try setting the targetSize 20x20

Comment: I changed targetSize 20x20, but it still fails.  My app only have this problem on iPad mini, and it works fine on iPhone device.

Comment: Too bad, I test this problem on iPad 1 and there is no iPad mini in my company.

Comment: I used the simulator to test it, all the iPad device has the same problem, including ipad pro, ipad mini4, ipad air2, ipad air. Thanks.

Comment: Please post actual code as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.